# OR-Tools in Flutter (Android)

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart, or-tools

I want to run an or-tools dependent script (using cp-model) on a Flutter-based Android app.

Is there a way to do that?

I wrote a python3 script with the or-tools API and it's doing what I wanted my app to do, but I couldn't find a way to run the python script on the flutter app...

Comment: There are no dart bindings for now, see https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/2830, a client-server approach is probably the solution

Answer (score 0):

No. Not with Python. Here are platforms : https://developers.google.com/optimization/install . In theory you can use Java,  but you'll have to code inside the Android project. check this link on how to https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/537 .
Personally I use or-tool for vrp. I run the or path on a machine and publish the results where apps can download results. Sometimes it isn't optimal, but it's close